# Tensorflow seq2seq multidimensional regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

**EDIT**: I edited my code to make seq2seq tutorial/exercises, here they are: 
https://github.com/guillaume-chevalier/seq2seq-signal-prediction

---

I try to do a sequence-to-sequence (seq2seq) regression with multidimensional inputs and outputs. I tried something which yields the following loss over time:

[image: Loss function over time]

The model completely fails to learn to predict a sinus cloned on every input and output dimensions, even if I try a very small learning rate.

The Tensorflow loss function built for RNNs seems to address the cases where we directly want to train labels or words embeddings, so I tried to compute the loss myself. Regarding that, I don't know how we should deal with the dec_inp (decoder input) variable, what I try to do seems not already done in Tensorflow, yet especially simple conceptually speaking (see title).

Here is the tensor graph:

[image]

There are some things on the graph I would not have expected, such as the link between the RMSProp optimiser and the basic_rnn_seq2seq.

Here is what I tried yet:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import tempfile
import math


rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell
seq2seq = tf.nn.seq2seq

tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()


# Neural net's parameters
seq_length = 5  # Inputs and outputs are sequences of 5 units
batch_size = 1  # Keeping it simple for now

# Each unit in the sequence is a float32 vector of lenght 10:
# Same dimension sizes just for simplicity now
output_dim = hidden_dim = input_dim = 10

# Optmizer: 
learning_rate = 0.0007  # Small lr to avoid problem
nb_iters = 2000  # Crank up the iters in consequence
lr_decay = 0.85  # 0.9 default
momentum = 0.01  # 0.0 default


# Create seq2seq's args
enc_inp = [tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, input_dim),
                          name="inp%i" % t)
           for t in range(seq_length)]

# sparse "labels" that are not labels: 
expected_sparse_output = [tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, output_dim),
                        name="expected_sparse_output%i" % t)
          for t in range(seq_length)]

# Decoder input: prepend some "GO" token and drop the final
# There might be a problem there too,
# my outputs are not tokens integer, but float vectors. 
dec_inp = [tf.zeros_like(enc_inp[0], dtype=np.float32, name="GO")] + enc_inp[:-1]

# Initial memory value for recurrence.
prev_mem = tf.zeros((batch_size, hidden_dim))


# Create rnn cell and decoder's sequence
cell = rnn_cell.GRUCell(hidden_dim)
# cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell] * layers_stacked_count)
dec_outputs, dec_memory = seq2seq.basic_rnn_seq2seq(
    enc_inp, 
    dec_inp, 
    cell
)


# Training loss and optimizer
loss = 0
for _y, _Y in zip(dec_outputs, expected_sparse_output):
    loss += tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(_y, _Y)) # Softmax loss
    # loss + tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(_y, _Y))

# The following commented loss function did not worked because 
# I want a sparse output rather than labels
# weights = [tf.ones_like(labels_t, dtype=tf.float32)
#            for labels_t in expected_sparse_output]
# loss = seq2seq.sequence_loss(dec_outputs, labels, weights)

tf.scalar_summary("loss", loss)
summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()

# optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, momentum)
# optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate)
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate, decay=lr_decay, momentum=momentum)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

logdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
print logdir
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(logdir, sess.graph)


sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

def gen_data_x_y():
    """
    Simply returns data of shape: 
        (seq_lenght, batch_size, output_dim)

    X is a sine of domain 0.0*pi to 1.5*pi
    Y is a sine of domain 1.5*pi to 3.0*pi

    To temporarily deal with the number of dimensions 
    """
    # Create the sine in x and it's continuation in y
    x = np.sin(np.linspace(0.0*math.pi, 1.5*math.pi, seq_length))
    y = np.sin(np.linspace(1.5*math.pi, 3.0*math.pi, seq_length))

    # Clone the sine for every input_dim. 
    # Normaly those dims would containt different signals 
    # happening at the same time of a single timestep of 
    # a single training example, such as other features of 
    # the signal such as various moving averages 
    x = np.array([x for i in range(input_dim)])
    y = np.array([y for i in range(output_dim)])
    x, y = x.T, y.T

    x = np.array([x]*batch_size) # simple for now: batch_size of 1
    y = np.array([y]*batch_size)
    # shape: (batch_size, seq_lenght, output_dim)
    x = np.array(x).transpose((1, 0, 2))
    y = np.array(y).transpose((1, 0, 2))
    # shape: (seq_lenght, batch_size, output_dim)

    # print "X_SHAPE: " + str(x.shape)
    return x, y

def train_batch(batch_size):
    """
    Training step: we optimize for every outputs Y at once, 
    feeding all inputs X

    I do not know yet how to deal with 
    the enc_inp tensor declared earlier
    """
    X, Y = gen_data_x_y()

    feed_dict = {
        enc_inp[t]: X[t] for t in range(seq_length)
    }
    feed_dict.update({expected_sparse_output[t]: Y[t] for t in range(seq_length)})
    feed_dict.update({prev_mem: np.zeros((batch_size, hidden_dim))})

    _, loss_t, summary = sess.run([train_op, loss, summary_op], feed_dict)
    return loss_t, summary

# Train
for t in range(nb_iters):
    loss_t, summary = train_batch(batch_size)
    print loss_t
    summary_writer.add_summary(summary, t)
summary_writer.flush()

# Visualise the loss
# !tensorboard --logdir {logdir}


# Test the training
X, Y = gen_data_x_y()

feed_dict = {
    enc_inp[t]: X[t] for t in range(seq_length)
}
# feed_dict.update({expected_sparse_output[t]: Y[t] for t in range(seq_length)})

outputs = sess.run([dec_outputs], feed_dict)


# Evaluate model
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)  # No scientific exponents
expected = Y[:,0,0]
print "Expected: "
print expected
print ""
print "The following results now represents each timesteps of a different output dim:"

mses = []
for i in range(output_dim):
    pred = np.array(outputs[0])[:,0,i]
    print pred
    mse = math.sqrt(np.mean((pred - expected)**2))
    print "mse: " + str(mse)
    mses.append(mse)
    print ""

print ""
print "FINAL MEAN SQUARED ERROR ON RESULT: " + str(np.mean(mses))
```

which prints:

```
/tmp/tmpVbO48U
5.87742
5.87894
5.88054
5.88221
5.88395
[...]
5.71791
5.71791
5.71791
5.71791
5.71791
Expected: 
[-1.         -0.38268343  0.70710678  0.92387953  0.        ]

The following results now represents each timesteps of a different output dim:
[-0.99999893 -0.99999893  0.96527898  0.99995273 -0.01624492]
mse: 0.301258140201

[-0.99999952 -0.99999952  0.98715001  0.9999997  -0.79249388]
mse: 0.467620401096

[-0.99999946 -0.9999994   0.97464144  0.99999654 -0.30602577]
mse: 0.332294862093

[-0.99999893 -0.99999893  0.95765316  0.99917656  0.36947867]
mse: 0.342355383387

[-0.99999964 -0.99999952  0.9847464   0.99999964 -0.70281279]
mse: 0.43769921227

[-0.99999744 -0.9999975   0.97723919  0.99999851 -0.39834118]
mse: 0.351715216206

[-0.99999964 -0.99999952  0.97650111  0.99999803 -0.37042192]
mse: 0.34544431708

[-0.99999648 -0.99999893  0.99999917  0.99999917  0.99999726]
mse: 0.542706750242

[-0.99999917 -0.99999917  0.96115535  0.99984574  0.12008631]
mse: 0.305224828554

[-0.99999952 -0.99999946  0.98291612  0.99999952 -0.62598646]
mse: 0.413473861107


FINAL MEAN SQUARED ERROR ON RESULT: 0.383979297224
```

It seems like a small thing is missing in my code, else a little bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For learning functions like sin(x), it is not good to use softmax loss.
* softmax losses are generally used for multi-class *discrete* predictions
* for continuous predictions, use, e.g., l2_loss

Also, since sin(x) is a function of x, I don't think you need an RNN for that. I'd really first try a 2-layer or 3-layer fully connected network. When that works, you can try an RNN. But sin(x) only depends on x, not on the whole history, so the recurrent state will be useless in this case.

Comment: In the end, I would like to predict the N next coefficients of some STFT on stocks market data, but for now, I focus on making the regression model work with simple data to then directly scale it, I already coded RNNs and ConvNets. Changing the softmax loss by MSE and using L2 loss helped, the rest was working fine. Many thanks!